# JupyterDash: how to get the flask callable?

Tags: python, flask, jupyter, jupyterdash

I have a script that runs jupyter dash app

```
app = JupyterDash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.run_server(port=8118, debug=False)
```

When the script is executed, I see

```
Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8118/

 * Serving Flask app 'webapp'
 * Debug mode: off
```

Now, how do I get the Flask 'callable' from the 'app' variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the Flask callable using

`application = app.server`